# ASP.NET My button doesn't work

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, web

I am new to ASP.NET in vb. I use Visual Studio 2010.

I downloaded a bootstrap and converted it into .aspx(I changed the index.html into index.aspx). Whenever I drag a button from toolbox I get this message "Inserting an asp.net control will convert the HTML in the page to an ASP.NET form and remove its current properties. Do you want to insert the ASP.NET control?".

When I clicked yes the button works but the design really got messed up. The side menu icons got larger.

I tried manually coding the button inside this

```
 <div class="row no-padding">
```

and code of the button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Login" />
```

And there I got a button that doesn't work even it has a postback url but the design is still fine.

I also tried converting this into a masterpage and include a content placeholder but same result.

Here is my entire code(It not a masterpage).

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Index.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>INDEX</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Icons-->
<script src="js/lumino.glyphs.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span>Lumino</span>Admin</a>
            <ul class="user-menu">
                <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><svg class="glyph stroked male-user"><use xlink:href="#stroked-male-user"></use></svg><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked male-user"><use xlink:href="#stroked-male-user"></use></svg> Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked gear"><use xlink:href="#stroked-gear"></use></svg> Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked cancel"><use xlink:href="#stroked-cancel"></use></svg> Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div id="sidebar-collapse" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidebar">
    <form role="search">
        <div class="form-group">

        </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav menu">
            <li><a href="index.aspx"><svg class="glyph stroked dashboard-dial"><use xlink:href="#stroked-dashboard-dial"></use></svg> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Employees.aspx"><svg class="glyph stroked calendar"><use xlink:href="#stroked-calendar"></use></svg> Widgets</a></li>
        <li><a href="charts.aspx"><svg class="glyph stroked line-graph"><use xlink:href="#stroked-line-graph"></use></svg> Charts</a></li>
        <li><a href="tables.aspx"><svg class="glyph stroked table"><use xlink:href="#stroked-table"></use></svg> Tables</a></li>
        <li><a href="forms.aspx"><svg class="glyph stroked pencil"><use xlink:href="#stroked-pencil"></use></svg> Forms</a></li>
        <li><a href="panels.aspx"><svg class="glyph stroked app-window"><use xlink:href="#stroked-app-window"></use></svg> Alerts &amp; Panels</a></li>
        <li><a href="icons.aspx"><svg class="glyph stroked star"><use xlink:href="#stroked-star"></use></svg> Icons</a></li>
    <li class="parent ">
            <a href="#">
                <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-1"><svg class="glyph stroked chevron-down"><use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-down"></use></svg></span> Dropdown 
            </a>
            <ul class="children collapse" id="sub-item-1">
                <li>
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        <svg class="glyph stroked chevron-right"><use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"></use></svg> Sub Item 1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        <svg class="glyph stroked chevron-right"><use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"></use></svg> Sub Item 2
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        <svg class="glyph stroked chevron-right"><use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"></use></svg> Sub Item 3
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><svg class="glyph stroked male-user"><use xlink:href="#stroked-male-user"></use></svg> Login Page</a></li>
    </ul>

</div><!--/.sidebar-->

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main">           
    <div class="row">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked home"><use xlink:href="#stroked-home"></use></svg></a></li>
            <li class="active">Icons</li>
        </ol>
    </div><!--/.row-->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.row-->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel panel-blue panel-widget ">
                <div class="row no-padding">

                <!--/HERE IS MY BUTTON*--><asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Login" PostBackUrl="~/Employees.aspx" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!--/.col-->
    </div><!--/.row-->
</div>  <!--/.main-->

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chart-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/easypiechart.js"></script>
<script src="js/easypiechart-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
    });

    !function ($) {
        $(document).on("click", "ul.nav li.parent > a > span.icon", function () {
            $(this).find('em:first').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
        });
        $(".sidebar span.icon").find('em:first').addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    }(window.jQuery);

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) $('#sidebar-collapse').collapse('show')
    })
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) $('#sidebar-collapse').collapse('hide')
    })
</script>   
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem in nesting form tags. You have two, nesting

Comment: Thanks for answering. This really solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your button should be inside a form element,
All your buttons and server side controls should exist inside the master form element, this is how asp.net forms is working.
And in your code, I can see that the button is outside the form, so form submit is executing